# Number of required Baalruns to level up

Tags: diablo-ii

How many hell Baalruns does a character need to level up from 80 to 81, then 81 to 82, ... 98 to 99. Does anyone have an estimate which takes into account the number of players too?

Baalrun definition: only killing Baal and Baal's minions in the Throne of Destruction (as current Battle.net bots do in a Baalrun).

Comment: This question is near impossible to answer, are we counting only the XP for killing baal? Because just to get you Baal you're going to get experience and that isn't going to be static.

Comment: This also changes based on number of players in the game, so if your doing multiplayer this fluctuates way too much.

Comment: Actually looks like someone did part of the math for you: http://www.diablo2.com/forum/baal-run-exp-t11582.html?s=f7054252c54f94aad0f556e3cec8328d&amp;

Comment: Thanks guys for the useful comments. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of tables indicating what you need for going from 90 to 99 on Baal runs, and you can extrapolate back from there.  The most up to date version I found was [here](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Guide:High_Level_Baal_Runs_to_99_v1.10,_by_jjscud_and_Reborn).

> The following figures represent how many Baal runs are required for
>   each level up, and the total journey, from level 90 to 99. This
>   assumes a player kills almost nothing on Worldstone Keep levels 2 and
>   3, then does all five packs of of Baal's Minions on `/players 8`, before
>   killing Baal himself on `/players 3+`. (There's a bug with Baal's
>   experience in v1.10+ where his experience value does not increase past
>   3 players.)

```
Start Level  End Level   Baal Runs   Total Baal Runs     % Complete
         90         91          20                20       0.36%
         91         92          30                50       0.90%
         92         93          45                90       1.63%
         93         94          60               155       2.61%
         94         95         110               265       4.8%
         95         96         210               475       8.6%
         96         97         450               925      16.7%
         97         98        1100              2025      36.6%
         98         99        3500              5525     100.0%
```

You should be able to extrapolate back from that to get the figures for levels 80 to 90, i.e. probably about 15 for 89 to 90, 12 to 88 to 89, 10 from 87 to 88, etc.

Comment: What conditions were these numbers under?

Comment: -1, there are more factors to figure out here than what was just put on the chart for extrapolation purposes.

Comment: just a FYI that at some point its faster to do diablo runs than baal runs because killing diablo is much easier to do and popping chaos seals isn't that big of a deal.  Also, the xp you gain differs depending on how many people are in the game.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: It's on the linked page: "This assumes a player kills almost nothing on Worldstone Keep levels 2 and 3, then does all five packs of of Baal's Minions on /players 8 [...]".

Comment: Thank you (and +1), dlanod! That estimate is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @palacsint there are other factors such as Anni's and Ondal's XP bonuses.

Comment: But those are straightforward and you can do that math yourself. "You have a 9% anni"? Great, just divide the number of runs by 1.09.... "You can't handle more than /players 6"? Great, the arreat summit's player exp calculations are up to date. You get 3/4 exp for that, so multiply the number of runs by 4/3. "You are running in an actual party instead of hoarding all of the players-8 exp single-player"? Hahah then this question becomes terrible and unanswerable.